# Use transition methods in Transitions-Everywhere library

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, material-design, android-transitions

I'm using TransitionsEverywhere library https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere and I'm wondering if is it possible to use methods `setSharedElementEnterTransition` or `setEnterTransition` using `TransitionInflater` from this library? Or is there another solution to use smooth and pretty transition between two fragments on Android 4?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Transitions-Everywhere library. You can check this issue on github account :

https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere/issues/11

I didn't try but this library seems like doing fragment transitions on pre-lollipop devices :

https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition